# Powershell script for folder's partition

Tags: powershell, partition

I'm trying to create a script which takes a folderpath as an argument and displays how full the partition with the folderpath is (0-100%).
In Linux I know of the `df -T $directory` command, but I cannot find any way of doing this in powershell. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate the output of df -T by using the following Get-CIMINstance call, which queries WMI/CIM for the information you're requesting.  As I'm not a linux expert, I'm not certain what specifically makes `df -t` a special command.  If this output doesn't capture what you need, can you provide some more info?

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_logicaldisk |  Select-Object SystemName,@{Name=‘Drive Letter‘;Expression={$_.DeviceID}},
                                                @{Name=‘Drive Label’;Expression={$_.VolumeName}},`
                                                @{Name=‘Size(MB)’;Expression={[int]($_.Size / 1MB)}},` 
                                                @{Name=‘FreeSpace%’;Expression={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size,2)*100}} | ft

> SystemName Drive Letter Drive Label Size(MB) FreeSpace%
  ---------- ------------ ----------- -------- ----------
  BEHEMOTH   B:           Aug 01 2014      172          0
  BEHEMOTH   C:                         171353         10
  BEHEMOTH   D:           Media         953867         20
  BEHEMOTH   E:           Big Betty    2861459         88
  BEHEMOTH   H:           VM            117726         37
  BEHEMOTH   T:                            250         94
```

**UPDATED**

Ok, I created a function called df using this code below.  You can provide a directory with -t to get the statistics for that particular partition.  Otherwise, if run without a param it will give us the disk statistics for the current disk.

```
Function df {
Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
                   Position=0)]
        [Alias("t")] 
        $directory = (get-item (get-location)))

    if ($PSBoundParameters.Count -ne 0){$directory = dget-item $directory}

    $root = $directory.Root.Name -replace '\\','%'
    Get-CimInstance Win32_logicaldisk -Filter ("DeviceID like '$root%'")|  Select-Object SystemName,@{Name=‘Drive Letter‘;Expression={$_.DeviceID}},
                                                @{Name=‘Drive Label’;Expression={$_.VolumeName}},`
                                                @{Name=‘Size(MB)’;Expression={"{0:N0}" -f [int]($_.Size / 1MB)}},` 
                                                @{Name=‘FreeSpace%’;Expression={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size,2)*100}}  | ft
}

df -t .\SampleDir
>SystemName Drive Letter Drive Label Size(MB) FreeSpace%
 ---------- ------------ ----------- -------- ----------
 DELLBOOK   C:           OSDisk      243,247          39
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm after. The important part is to run this script with a folder path I send into args[0] (as an argument when executing the script). And only the partition containing this folder will display its free space percentage.
Are there no objects, methods or properties with the function of showing this percentage without calculating it yourself?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  How would a folder have a percent of free space?  Are you looking to provide a folder path and get the amount of free space on that disk?

Comment: Correct, but partition, not disk. :-)

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  I'll update my post later today with that approach. I'll also post a new comment so you'll know to check this out again.

Comment: By the way -T is just an alias of the proper parameter for this function, -Directory.  I thought -T would make you feel more at home in PowerShell, so I made sure to support it :)

Comment: Brilliant! This helped me getting the result I wanted. Thank you very much :-)